# Load PostgreSQL table from CSV with data with commas between brackets

Tags: postgresql, csv, brackets

I've been given some CSV data I need to load into a PostgreSQL table with the following format:

```
7227, {text with, commas}, 10.0, 3.0, text with no commas
```

I want my table rows to appear as:

```
   7227 | text with, commas | 10.0 | 3.0 | text with no commas
```

How can I use COPY and get it to ignore commas between the brackets?

I'm trying to avoid pre-processing the file, although that is an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid you'll have to edit the file. This format should be ok:

```
7227, "text with, commas", 10.0, 3.0, text with no commas
```

Alternatively

```
7227, text with\, commas, 10.0, 3.0, text with no commas
```

according to this principle in [the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/interactive/sql-copy.html):

> Backslash characters (\) can be used in the COPY data to quote data
>   characters that might otherwise be taken as row or column delimiters.
>   In particular, the following characters must be preceded by a
>   backslash if they appear as part of a column value: backslash itself,
>   newline, carriage return, and the current delimiter character.