# How to escape commas from column values in CSV when importing table to Postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to insert csv file in postgresql database

the code is

```
COPY meta.fk_payment_temp
     FROM 'C:\Users\YAM\Downloads\wfgyrnyjumou_p\transaction-2014-04-01-2014-04-30.csv' with csv header delimiter ',' ;
```

but there is some column value have comma

like `"24 mar, 2014","abc, xyz"`   etc

how i can solve this in postgresql query ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Load PostgreSQL table from CSV with data with commas between brackets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30380040/load-postgresql-table-from-csv-with-data-with-commas-between-brackets)

Comment: What exactly requires "solving" here? You haven't explained any problem, shown any error messages, etc.

Comment: That should work fine. It isn't a duplicate of the cited question, but the 'with csv' should be sufficient. If it didn't work, you should show us what happened.

Comment: @CraigRinger Error is  extra data after column

Comment: @Shubhambatra Well... it looks sane from the info provided. So please edit the question to add a complete few lines of the problem CSV input and the table structure as a CREATE TABLE statement. Make sure the error actually happens with the sample data.